# call a request api function in views.py with ajax

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

Forgive me for stupid questions, but I do not really understand how such relationships work in the Web-development.

I have views.py: [image]

As you can see there is a connection to the api and the information I need is parsed.

Then in my template I have a listener that shows when the user reached the bottom of the page:

[image]

As you can see at the bottom of the template i have ajax block where I again connect to api
But now the most important question **is this the right way**?

Do I need to connect json and fill my arrays and elements in the ajax block one time more? BUT It's all done in `views.py`.In general, is it realistic to call `def main(request)` from ajax all the time and append all my arrays and elements automatically? I need like smth this :

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
  $.ajax({
     url: "{% url 'main' %}",//my request which appends all my arrays automatically
     type: "GET",
     success: function () {

     },
     error: function () {
});
```

Sorry for such questions but I do not understand how such bundles work

As for the counter of connected pages, I'll deal with this later, I need information now in which direction to move in general

Answer (score -1):

It's not a good way. Generally, Django view does not have anything to do with it. You should directly call the URL from ajax and parse the answer in your JS, on the page itself. However, if it is necessary to process the response from that URL in some way, then you should create a separated view that will process the response and return the corresponding JSON as a response.

So the first view only needs to have a template response, and your ajax script on the page should call another view and take over from JSON. This second view sends the request to that remote URL and processes it, then returns JSON as a response.

For this other view, I recommend Django Rest Framework, but this is not necessary if it's a simple feature.